# Input value not visible in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, input

This input value should be "Paris" but it does not display.
What is wrong with my code?

```js
(function(angular, undefined) {
  var mon_app = angular.module('mon_app', []);
  angular.module('mon_app').controller('monctrl', function($scope) {})
}(window.angular));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="app" ng-app="mon_app">

<head lang="fr" class="app">
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="monctrl">
    This input value is "Paris"
    <input name="lieu" ng-model="lieu" type="text" value="Paris" />
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It wont work that way. You need to set `$scope.lieu="paris"` in your controller to set default value

Comment: or you can use `ng-init`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot mix regular HTML (the `value` attribute of your input) and the angular-driven `ng-model`. The input will always display the value of what's in `ng-model`, here `lieu`, hence you should iniialize `$scope.lieu` with the Paris value.

```js
(function(angular, undefined) {
  var mon_app = angular.module('mon_app', []);
  angular.module('mon_app').controller('monctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.lieu = "Paname";
  })
}(window.angular));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="app" ng-app="mon_app">

<head lang="fr" class="app">
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="monctrl">
    This input value is "{{lieu}}"
    <input name="lieu" ng-model="lieu" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: @user2761037 If that helped you please +1 and/or accept the answer :)

Comment: I would love to, but i actually created my stackoverflow account to ask this question. Vote Up requires 15 reputation.

Comment: I see. Let's call it, échange de bon procédé ;-)