# angular app delete input form UNWILLING from wordpress after reloading/submitting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, custom-post-type, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have a form:

```
<table class="widefat" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <tr>
        <td><label for="name_pokemon"><?php _e( "Name", "cpt" ); ?></label></td>
        <td><input id="name_pokemon_val" maxlength="{{a1Max}}" name="name_pokemon" type="text" ng-model="a1" ng-change="update()" value="<?php echo esc_textarea( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name_pokemon', true) ); ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Name', 'cpt' ); ?>"></td>
        <td>Length: {{a1.length}} Remaining: {{remainingA}}</td>
    </tr></table>
```

My script:

```
<script>
            var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

            function MyCtrl($scope) {
                    $scope.a1='';
                   
                var maxA = 21;
          
                $scope.update = function()  {
                    $scope.remainingA = maxA - ($scope.a1.length);

                    $scope.a1Max = maxA;
                    
                }
                $scope.update();}</script>
```

Now I have the problem that after I submit my Custom Post Type it reset the input data.

How can I fix that?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076773/input-value-not-visible-in-angularjs)

The angular App just show the values of the app...
I fixed it with initalize the var of the app with the value from wordpress

now it looks like that:

```
$scope.a1='<?php echo esc_textarea( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name_pokemon', true) ); ?>'; 
                    $scope.a2='<?php echo esc_textarea( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'code_card_pokemon', true) ); ?>';
                    $scope.b1='<?php echo esc_textarea( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'lang_pokemon', true) ); ?>';
                    $scope.b2='<?php echo esc_textarea( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'code_pokemon', true) ); ?>';
                    $scope.c1='<?php echo esc_textarea( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'setname_pokemon', true) ); ?>';
```

After initalize the scope it worked perfectly.

I hope I could help someone